# How to postpone refetching of invalidated RTK query

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

RTK query seems to work so that when cached results get invalidated, the invalidated query is being re-fetched **immediately**. I would expect that a re-fetch would execute when the program requests invalidated data, but not sooner.

### Real world use case

Suppose I have an app where the user needs to login - so something that majority of webapps do. Let's say I have three endpoints:

- **login** mutation - logs the user in
- **getAuthInfo** query - gets the authenticated session data (has `providesTags: ['AuthData']` set)
- **logout** mutation - logs the user out (has `invalidatesTags: ['AuthData']` set)

When the user logs in, the code requests authenticated session info. And this data naturally gets cached as many pages may need certain data of this information.

**But** when the user later logs out, the cached data gets invalidated (as per auto-invalidation tags settings), and gets therefore immediately re-fetched by the RTK query lib. Such a call fails with HTTP 401 for obvious reasons.

### Question

How can I prevent an invalidated query from being immediately re-fetched? In the upper example I would want data to be re-fetched when the code makes a new call to the endpoint **but not sooner**. Is it possible to control re-fetching behaviour in RTK Query?

Comment: I feel like this is the use case for https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#invalidatetags where you call that when the time is right per your logic and then you make logout not automatically invalidateTags

Answer (score 1):

The best way to invalidate tags with a delay is to use the `onQueryStarted()` method and combine it with a `setTimeout` and the `api.util.invalidateTags()` method from Redux toolkit.

```js
    completeCheckListTask: builder.mutation<TaskResponse, TaskCompleteArg>({
      query: ({ body, pathParams }) => ({
        url: `checklist/${pathParams.id}/${pathParams.exampleId}/task/${pathParams.anotherId}`,
        method: 'PATCH',
        body,
      }),
      async onQueryStarted(props, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        await queryFulfilled
        setTimeout(() => {
          dispatch(api.util.invalidateTags(['Checklist']))
        }, 3000)
      },
    }),
```

You can read more at the docs here https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/manual-cache-updates

Comment: But that doesn't delay the fetch until it's requested the next time, but delays by a predefined amount of time which is not what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `dispatch(apiSlice.util.resetApiState())` on logout, which may work for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to have a flag `isAuthenticated` and if you logged out set this flag to `false`.
Once the user successfully logged out have a `skip: !isAuthenticated` for the queries that invalidated after logout.